# find eigen values of given matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

> If $w$ is a non-real cube root of unity, then eigenvalues of the matrix:

$$ \begin{pmatrix} 1&1&1 \\ 1&w&w^2 \\ 1&w^2&w^4 \end{pmatrix}
   \begin{pmatrix} 1&0&0 \\ 0&-1&0 \\ 0&0&0 \end{pmatrix}
   \begin{pmatrix} 1&1&1 \\ 1&1/w&1/w^2 \\ 1&1/w^2&1/w^4 \end{pmatrix} $$

> are which of these:

(a) $1,-1,0$

(b) $\frac{1}{3},-\frac{1}{3},0$

(c) $1,w,w^2$

(d) $3,-3,0$

Please suggest some trick to find eigen value of this matrix given as product of 3 matrices, because to actually compute product of these matrix would not be a feasible idea in a exam.

Comment: Actually, calculating the product may not take so much time as to trying to ifnd out a "trick". After all, the center matrix is almost an identity matrix and I see bunch of reciprocals in the third w.r.t the first.

Comment: Product becomes little complicated

Comment: The hint of Omnomnomnom is very good. Think about it, and remember that $\omega^3=1$, so $\omega^3-1=0 \iff (1+\omega+\omega^2)(\omega-1)=0$, but $\omega \neq 1$ so $1 + \omega + \omega^2 =0$. Also if $\frac{1}{3}PAP^{-1}$ has eigenvalues $1,-1$, then $PAP^{-1}$ has eigenvalues multiplied by $3$.

Comment: For such kind of questions you are not asked to make alot of calculations but to think how does the things look like. How one can represent things in different forms. Here one needs to know eigen value decomposition and how this problem looks like it. I find @omnomnomnom s answer useful. The left and right matrices are not orthonormal and the scaling factors should affect inversly the elements of the diagonal matrix.

Comment: @Ale can u throw some more light on how $ PAP^{-1}$ has eigen values multiplied by 3?

Comment: @singularity I do not know your math background. The solution of Omnomnomnom is ofcourse excellent, but does require some knowledge of matrix algebra. I respectfully suspect you are not "there" yet. But why is matrix multiplication complicated? The first with the second is very easy as the second matrix is almost a unit matrix. So essentially you have to worry about one multiplication of two 3by3's By the standard of most people on this forum, that is not considered very difficult...

Comment: If 1st matrix is unitary then its inverse shud be its conjugate transpose, but third matrix is not conjugate transpose of 1st matrix.

Comment: @singularity $\text{det}(PAP^{-1}-\lambda I) = \text{det}(PAP^{-1}-P\lambda P^{-1}) = \text{det}(P(AP^{-1}-\lambda IP^{-1}) = \text{det}(P(A-\lambda I)P^{-1}) = \text{det}(P) \text{det}(A-\lambda I) \text{det}(P)^{-1} = \text{det}(A-\lambda I)$, So the eigenvalues of $A$ and $PAP^{-1}$ are the same

Comment: @Ale had the 3rd matrix been inverse of first one then, product of these three matrix would have same eigen value as middle one. But are they inverses,? That needs to be seen

Comment: @singularity have you tried to multiply them? Try it. And read again my comment above, there is all you need to know to show that they are inverse to each other.

Comment: @Ale Ya alright thank you very very much

Comment: @singularity you are welcome :)

Comment: @singularity it is useful to note that in general,
$$
\overline{\omega} = |\omega|^2/\omega
$$
so, in the case that $|\omega| = 1$, we have
$$
\overline{\omega} = \omega^{-1}
$$
so, we indeed have that the two matrices at the end are the conjugate transpose of each other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** note that the matrix
$$
\frac 1{\sqrt{3}}\pmatrix{
1&1&1\\
1&\omega & \omega^2\\
1 & \omega^2 & \omega^4
}
$$
is unitary (since its columns are orthonormal). From there, it's easy to see that
$$
\left[
\frac 1{\sqrt{3}}\pmatrix{
1&1&1\\
1&\omega & \omega^2\\
1 & \omega^2 & \omega^4
}
\right]^{-1}=
\frac 1{\sqrt{3}}\pmatrix{
1&1&1\\
1&\omega^{-1} & \omega^{-2}\\
1 & \omega^{-2} & \omega^{-4}
}
$$

Comment: I haven't done orthonormal Yet. So I dont know why columns are orthonormal.kindly give way of how to see they are orthonormal.

Comment: Orthonormal means that any two columns are mutually orthogonal, and every column has length (AKA magnitude, norm) $1$.

Answer (score 1):

hint: first and third matrix are 'nearly' inverse of each other . let the first matrix be $A$ second $B$ , the third if you notice is $3A^{-1}$. so now $3ABA^{-1}-kAIA^{-1}=0$
therefore the solution of $k$ is nothing but $|3B-kI|=0$ which is quite simple.note:$3B-kI=0$ does not have to hold true , as product together can be zero. the determinant of other two matrices is non zero so $|B|$ has to be zero. hope this helps

Comment: sorry for giving d answer late , was caught up in something. if any doubts feel free to ask